# Телеграмм бот, не отправляется стикер от пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Хочу, чтобы бот реагировал на отправку стикера пользователем
Именно последний декоратор должен работать так, но бот на него не реагирует, остальное рабочее

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Опача, застартовался')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветос')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пока')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'Отправь стикер с попугом':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBFJpfF1S4E2A_-_LenXaARO2xLf4CHQACz3IAAp7OCwAB1R6GX4tzWG0aBA')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'одолжи сотку':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgEAAxkBAAEBFJxfF1dkXMoyy-d3pQtwrf3VGiE5vwACtwEAAlXgShfvU1iAwWOOmBoE')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def send_sticker(message):
    if message.sticker == 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBFJpfF1S4E2A_-_LenXaARO2xLf4CHQACz3IAAp7OCwAB1R6GX4tzWG0aBA':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты отправил мне стикер')

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать `message.sticker.file_id`, это id стикера.
Мне, конечно, кажется, что `'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBFJpfF1S4E2A_-_LenXaARO2xLf4CHQACz3IAAp7OCwAB1R6GX4tzWG0aBA'` немного странный id, но вы легко можете заново узнать нужный id:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def send_sticker(message):
    print(message.sticker.file_id)
```

Также, если вам интересно, то `message.sticker` - это словарь (не строка, поэтому у вас не работало):

```
{'file_id': 'CAACAgQAAxkBAAM0XyloC6nx7N2XgZOzPdvrgvBcOywAAt4CAAJSOZMG91SyalTt7u8aBA', 'width': 512, 'height': 371, 'thumb': {'file_size': 2902, 'height': 93, 'width': 128, 'file_id': 'AAMCBAADGQEAAzRfKWgLqfHs3ZeBk7M92-uC8Fw7LAAC3gIAAlI5kwb3VLJqVO3u7yeUYTAABAEAB20AA7QkAAIaBA'}, 'emoji': '�', ' set_name': 'CatPusheen', 'mask_position': None, 'file_size': 14262, 'is_animated': False}
```